# How to extract multiple paths from a single string of URLs in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, url, regex, regexextract

How can I get a subrange of second to last element in a formula under Google Sheets?

I'm trying to extract all occurrences of `https://example.com/*` in a cell which may contain multiple URLs scattered across a string like:

```
abc https://example.com/abc https://google.com/ghi https://example.com/def/abc
```

so that I get the paths in a single string, separated by spaces as follows:

```
abc def/abc
```

As SPLIT looks the easiest way for that, I need to get rid of the first item in a formula like:

```
=join("
",
  arrayformula(
    regexextract(
      split(A5, "https://example.com/", false, true),
      "[a-zA-Z0-9/\?=_]+")
    )
  )
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the contents of the cell.

Comment: I made some guesses of what OP intends to use as input and output. Please correct if wrong but this makes it more useful for others and allows a concrete solution.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer Your sample data is just right for the problem at hand. Thanks for the well-designed solution and a step-by-step explanation for it!

Comment: You are welcome :) please accept the solution too, to show it solved the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the basic concept right just piece it together step by step. This does the job:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(" ",ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
  REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1," ",TRUE,TRUE),
  "https://example.com/(\S+)"),""))),"\s+"," ")
```

1. You `split` the string at whitespaces, this is safe because URLs don't contain white space so you're definitely not breaking them up. This gives you an array of strings
2. Since you want all the paths for all the domains starting with `example.com` you `REGEXEXTRACT` exactly those paths and only those paths using a capturing group `(\S+)`.
3. Now you will get an error for every string that doesn't have the correct domain. So you use `IFERROR` to simply replace those strings with empty strings, we don't care about those.
4. We wrap all of this in `ARRAYFORMULA` since the output of split is an array. So now we have an array of empty strings and paths.
5. We now `JOIN` them together using white space, again, paths don't contain white space so we're not losing any structure.
6. Lastly, we're cleaning up any white space tuples since they're unnecessary and not pretty using `REGEXREPLACE`. Done!

The result is a string of all the paths for the correct domain only, separated by one whitespace each.

Tip: I built this formula step by step, not as one big formula but piecewise in exactly the sequence outlined above to keep things manageable.

[image]

Comment: One thing I missed: looks like your approach results in a leading space whenever the cell does not starts with the URL. I discovered that when I used line break instead of space. How can I get rid of leading separator?

Comment: You're right about the leading space - if you mind it you can replace it with another ``REGEXREPLACE(string, "^\s","")`` where the command above is to be put in place of string.

Comment: If possible, I wish we could have a cleaner way, removing an array item right after initial REGEXTRACT(SPLIT) functions, which brings us back to the original "second to last element subrange" question we originally started with :-)

Comment: @wassrubleff I'm not sure I understand what you mean by removing array item, can you explain?

Comment: I meant the following. The leading separator in your answer is there for strings starting with non-URL because the SPLIT > REGEXTRACT results in an empty first item, and then it is JOINed together using a space which results in a leading separator in the resulting string. But now I also realize that any multiple non-URL words occurred between any two URLs also result in repeated delimiter which still should be addressed--again it would be cleaner to remove it before JOINing together, but I'm not big expert on how we can filter the pre-JOIN array to contain only non-empty items.